# Does a roof unit HVAC have a pilot light?

Tags: hvac, gas

This may be a silly question, but I want to know if there is a pilot light that needs to be reignited after I turn the house main gas line off and on.

[image]

Comment: Without the model it's impossible to say for certain, but I'd put money on the answer being 'no'. Usually these use a hot surface igniter.

Comment: @KMJ Or a spark igniter. But either way, not a pilot light and almost always the furnace part is indoors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### TL;DR No

*Oops. KMJ spotted the gas valve. So there is gas after all. But still no pilot light.*

This unit appears to be a roof-mounted HVAC system that includes the furnace and air handler, and I suspect a compressor (for air conditioning) as well. All in one big box that is plopped on top of the ductwork. Interesting.

However, typical furnaces for the last few *decades* have included electronic ignition instead of using a pilot light. That can be a hot surface igniter or a spark igniter - but not a pilot light. That is much more energy efficient because typically a furnace is only needed ~ 1/2 of the year and the rest of the time you use either air conditioning or nothing at all. Burning a pilot light when you don't actually need the heat doesn't make much sense.

Storage tank hot water heaters, on the other hand, often have a pilot light. Since they need to produce hot water all year long, the extra heat from a pilot light at least goes towards helping (a little) to warm up the water, so it isn't a total waste. And decades ago furnaces often used a pilot light as well, so the question is reasonable but almost certainly the answer here is "No".

Comment: These are called 'package unit' HVACs. They are common in commercial but I've never seen one around here in residential. This one could be gas/heat pump or gas/electric with AC. You still got my updoot for a solid answer.